# a problem about asymptotic analysis of an irregular singular point of one ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

The differential equation $y^{\prime \prime}+x^{-2} e^{1 / x} \sin \left(e^{1 / x}\right) y=0$ has an irregular singular point at $x=0$. Show that if we make the exponential substitution $y=e^{s}$, it is not correct to assume $S^{\prime \prime} \ll\left(S^{\prime}\right)^{2}$ as $x \rightarrow 0+$. What is the leading behavior of $y(x)$?

$\textbf{Remark.}$ The definition of the leading behavior of a solution to ODE is that the first term of the infinite series representation of the local behavior of the solution.

The first question can be easily solved using the method given in the statement. I wonder how to find the form of the solution $y(x)$. But it's hard to solve this equation straightly. Can anybody give some valuable idea on it? Thank you!

Comment: If $(S')^2 << S''$, then integrating once we get $S' = -\cos(e^{1/x})+A(x)$, which is consistent with the assumption for $A' <<x^{-2}e^{1/x}\sin(e^{1/x})$. I'm suspicious of this because it doesn't look like we can proceed. We can at least say that the controlling factor of $y$ is *not* of the form $\exp(x^{-n})$ for $n>0$